# AnyLogic 7: Excel access library (Apache POI) is not specified

Tags: apache-poi, simulation, anylogic

AnyLogic 7: Excel access library (Apache POI) is not specified

I'm trying to use the AnyLogic `ExcelFile` class, but it appears that AnyLogic can't find the required Apache POI library:

```
Error during model startup:
Excel access library (Apache POI) is not specified (or is specified incorrectly) in the classpath
Caused by: org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/InvalidFormatException
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Excel access library (Apache POI) is not specified (or is specified incorrectly) in the classpath
    at com.xj.anylogic.engine.Engine.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.xj.anylogic.engine.Engine.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.xj.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.xj.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.run(Unknown Source)
    at generic_agent_based_model_with_births_and_deaths.Simulation.executeShapeControlAction(Simulation.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/InvalidFormatException
    at generic_agent_based_model_with_births_and_deaths.ExcelDataSource.onStartup(ExcelDataSource.java:668)
    at generic_agent_based_model_with_births_and_deaths.ExcelDataSource.start(ExcelDataSource.java:652)
    at generic_agent_based_model_with_births_and_deaths.Main.start(Main.java:1046)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 7 more
```

How do I fix this?

Some notes:

1. I am working with a model initially developed by someone else. I am assuming the model was initially built for AnyLogic 6.9, but I am using AnyLogic 7.0.3.
2. I assume that AnyLogic is supposed to import the POI library automatically: any idea what it did wrong / what I did wrong to cause AnyLogic to fail?
3. To head off any confusion, `ExcelDataSource` is a wrapper class I've created to simplify `ExcelFile` for our use case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you make sure you have all the Apache POI jars on your classpath and available to your application?

Comment: There are specific versions imported by AnyLogic, so a generic POI doesn't work. See Tatiana's answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AnyLogic uses Apache POI library for working with Excel spreadsheets. But it is disabled by default as unnecessary. You should drop Excel File element from Connectivity palette to be able to use Apache POI methods. Another way - add the library to model dependencies list (see Dependencies section of the model properties view).

Comment: To all those who read this in the future: you cannot simply *use* the `ExcelFile` class. You *must* drag an ExcelFile element from the palette to the workspace.

Comment: One does not simply `ExcelFile` into Mordor :-)